# ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(): Add value to list on update

Tags: c#

I am using a `ConcurrentDictionary<String,List<String>>`. I want to use the `AddOrUpdate` method such that if a list already exists for a key, then the value gets added to the list of values. Since the function that I supply to `AddOrUpdate` method needs to return a List, I think I want to do this:

```
public void AddValue( String key, String value)
{
    _dictionary.AddOrUpdate( key, new List<string> { value},
        ( k, oldValue ) => UpdateValueList( oldValue, value) );
}

private List<String> UpdateValueList( List<String> list, String value)
{
    if ( !list.Contains( value) )
    {
        list.Add( value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is this a good way of handling this scenario, or should I do something different?

Comment: Probably you should pass `new List<string> { value}` as delegate, as of now you're creating new list always and goes as garbage. Also consider wrapping `List` in your custom type

Comment: You should probably be using `HashSet`s instead of `List`s, since you don't want a collection to contain the same value more than once.

Comment: Do you need concurrency? If not, there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: Very good question. Answers below point that this is not thread safe. Would it make a difference if you use `ConcurrentDictionary<String,ConcurrentCollection<String>>`? What was your final solution?

Answer (score 1):

Given you're using a `ConcurrentDictionary` I assume you're looking for a thread-safe solution.  Your solution isn't thread-safe, since the `List<T>` class isn't thread-safe.

To make a thread-safe solution you need to make sure you synchronise all access to the `List<T>` class from within your class, and ensure you never expose the List outside your class (if you need to, you'll need to clone it).

Difficult to be more precise without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

**UPDATE**

Just to provide an example about the lack of thread-safety.

- Consider a race condition between two threads that call your AddOrUpdate method.
- `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't hold a lock while running your `addValueFactory` and `updateValueFactory` methods.  This is a general design principle: don't hold locks while calling out to external code, since this can cause all sorts of problems including reentrancy.
- Therefore two threads can run the `UpdateValueList` method concurrently using the same input list, which isn't thread-safe.

It could probably be made thread-safe if you wrap every access to the list in a lock, but I'd need to see the rest of the code for your class to be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  Doesn't `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` synchronize access to the `TValue`s?

Comment: Yes, let's assume I do all the other requisite things needed to make the class thread safe. What I'm asking is if there is a better paradigm to use when updating a list (or hashset) when it's the value in a concurrent hashmap. All the other examples I've seen, the value is just an interger value or something and they simply update it.

Comment: List<T> will not be thread safe if it is referenced and used outside the context of the ConcurrentDictionary. If you need to guarantee thread safety for both the Dictionary and the collection you can swap out List<T> for ConcurrentBag<T>.

Comment: "don't hold locks while calling out to external code" This is a critical point that would have saved a HUGE outage where I work recently. Any chance you have a good reference for this principle that I could share with people to get them over to "my side?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes I realize this is old, but couldn't find a good answer, so putting my solution here to help others.

Given a ConcurrentDictionary, where the value is a collection (List, ConcurentBag, etc) that you wish to add values.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<int>> myDictionary = 
                    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<int>>();
```

Check to see if the key is there, if not, add the key and initialize your collection.

```
                if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
                    {

                    myDictionary.TryAdd(            
                        key: myKey,                 
                        value: new ConcurrentBag<int>());   

                    }
```

Now that you know the key is there and your collection can be modified, add your value into the collection.

```
myDictionary[myKey].Add(myValue);
```

Full Example With Data:

```
    static void concurentDictionaryList()
        {
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<int>> myDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<int>>(); //Dictionary containing a List
        int[][] mySampleValues = new int[10][];  //Collection Of sample Data
        int myKey;
        int myValue;

                                                //Build Some Sample Data         
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            mySampleValues[i] =
                Enumerable.Range(
                    start: 1,
                    count: mySampleValues.Length - i)
                    .ToArray();
            }                              


                                                    //Loop through each sample value
        for (int i = 0; i < mySampleValues.Length; i++)  
            {

            myValue =                               //Get the value I want to add to each key;
                i;                                      

                                                    //Loop though each sample value's collection
            for (int ii = 0; ii < mySampleValues[i].Length; ii++)           
                {

                myKey =
                    mySampleValues[i][ii];          //Get the value I'll use for the key

                if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
                    {

                    myDictionary.TryAdd(            // If the key doesn't exist in the dictionary,
                        key: myKey,                 // then add the key and initilize the List for that key
                        value: new ConcurrentBag<int>());   

                    }

                myDictionary[myKey].Add(myValue);   // Since I know the key is in the Dictionary 
                                                    // and the list has been initilized, 
                                                    // I just add the value to my list.  
                }
            }
                                
                                                    //Validate by printing
        foreach (var itemKey in myDictionary.Keys)
            {

            Debug.WriteLine(""
                +$"{itemKey.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' ')}: "   
                +$"{string.Join(separator: ", ",values: myDictionary[itemKey].ToArray().OrderBy(o=>o))}");

            }
                      

        //Printed Results:
                        // 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                        // 2: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                        // 3: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
                        // 4: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
                        // 5: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
                        // 6: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                        // 7: 0, 1, 2, 3
                        // 8: 0, 1, 2
                        // 9: 0, 1
                        //10: 0




        }
```

**Note: When picking a collection type, note the thread safety comments that are already in this thread.